# Unlock command is overwriting private channels in discord

Tags: python, discord, pycord

My discord server has a bunch of private channels, which only people with the role "verified" can access. My unlock command has a parameter that unlocks every channel in the server by setting the permission of every channel to send_messages = True, so by this logic, even the @everyone role would be able to access private channels when I use the command

Code:

```
@client.slash_command(name='unlock', guild_ids=[insert guild id here])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels = True)
async def unlock(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel=None, setting = None):
    if setting == 'server':
        for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages = True, reason = f'{ctx.author.name} unlocked {channel.name} with --server')
        await ctx.respond(f'{ctx.author} unlocked the entire server')
    if channel is None:
        channel = ctx.message.channel
    else:
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages = True, reason = f'{ctx.author.name} unlocked {channel.name}')
        await ctx.respond(f'unlocked {ctx.channel.mention}')
```

I tried adding a command that would re-add a prefix for private channels and could edit the permissions of already existing channels, so if you had a global channel you could make it private. I expected for it to do exactly that but instead it created completely new private channels

Answer (score 1):

Setting `send_messages` does not imply channel view access, they are disconnected permissions (`view_channel` controls this).

It is safe to set/unset message send without exposing hidden channels. Be aware though, that locking all channels in this way will cause everyone everywhere to be unable to send messages, unless they have the `administrator` permission, or a channel override to send messages.